# I want to assign the pointer next to point to new node as indicated in the line having error

Tags: c

```
void enqueue(struct input **start, struct input **rear, char *elem)
{
    struct input *newnode = (struct input *)malloc(sizeof(struct input));
    newnode->data = elem;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    printf("%s\n", newnode->data);
    if(rear!=NULL)
    {
        printf("further");
        rear->next=newnode;(I am having an error in this line)
    }
```

Comment: Include the relevant code, i.e., how `struct input` is defined. Include the error message. Format your code: Indent by 4 or use the code button to mark it as code, indent per block level.

Comment: Quick guess: `rear` is pointer to pointer to struct, but you only use one dereferencing operator when you access it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, but more urgently, please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You've not provided enough information for us to be able to help much.  You've not shown how `struct input` is defined, nor have you shown the exact compiler error you're getting.  The structure definition is crucial; the error message is merely important.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
rear->next=newnode;
```

with

```
(*rear)->next=newnode;
```

`rear` has a type of `struct input **`, so it is a pointer to a pointer. You first need to take the value of `rear`, that will give you a pointer to struct. Then you can use `->` operator on this pointer.

Comment: An error is still appearing in the line:                                                                         (*rear)->next=newnode;    error(Thread1;EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address 0x8))
    }

Comment: You should post an MCVE as an edit to your original question.